# HDFS Delegation token expired even after adding principle to command line

Tags: hadoop, spark-streaming, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I'm running a spark streaming job in hadoop. The machine is kerberized and it ran fine for 42 Hours and fails due to HDFS token delegation expiry.

I even have the crontab set up for kinit command that runs for every 8 hours and I have the Max-renew lifetime token for 10 hours.

> Failed due to error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): token (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token

I'm also running the job with principle in the command line while initiating it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue Solved...!
Added the following config to spark command line while initiating the job and it worked.

> --conf spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true

or you can change this at yarn config level to impact globally.

I tested it its running fine for 3 days.

Thanks

Comment: also tried adding "--conf mapreduce.job.complete.cancel.delegation.tokens=false" , this helped me to run the job for more than a week and it is Solved..!

Comment: I add "--conf spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true" and "--conf mapreduce.job.complete.cancel.delegation.tokens=false" when I submit spark streamming job,but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a couple years late, but just in case anybody stumbles on this:

Disabling the FS cache (`fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true`) means `FileSystem#get` will create a new FileSystem every time it is called.

Instead, it looks the app master can refresh the delegation token if you pass `--keytab` to `spark-submit`:

- https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/cm_sg_yarn_long_jobs.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba-590cb1d1-149e9ca9886--7a82
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#yarn-mode

Answer (score 0):

Even after setting this configuration, Spark job will fail. We were facing the same issue.

A token is valid only for 24 hrs. Yarn renew the token every 24 hrs automatically until it reaches the max lifetime (which is 7 days) then the token cannot get renewed anymore and needs to be reissued, because of which the application will fail.

This might help to solved the problem.
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Long-running-Spark-streaming-job-that-crashes-on-HDP-2-3-4-7/td-p/181658

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.